# Pushing Git submodules into a separate working tree

Tags: git, git-submodules

On our staging server we have a bare repo that gets pushed to.  This has a post-receive hook that then does all of our deploy stuff, which all gets checked out into a separate working tree (which doesn't have a git folder).

So the setup is this:

bare repo is at

```
/var/www/apps/e_learning_staging/elearning_resource.git
```

working tree is at

```
/var/www/apps/e_learning_staging/www
```

This setup currently works fine.  However, I've added four submodules to the project (which actually only use two separate repos - each is duplicated in two places in the project).  The submodule repos are all on a different server.

These are all listed in the bare repo's config file, which looks like this:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0 
  filemode = true
  bare = true
  logallrefupdates=true
  worktree = /var/www/apps/e_learning_staging/www
  gitdir = /var/www/apps/e_learning_staging/elearning_resource.git
  [submodule "public/assets/players/virgin_lesson_viewer"]
    url = user@another.server.com:/home/charangadh/source_code/git/virgin_lesson_viewer.git
  [submodule "public/assets/players/virgin_lesson_viewer_staging"]
    url = user@another.server.com:/home/charangadh/source_code/git/virgin_lesson_viewer_staging.git
  [submodule "public/assets/dvd_files/Virgin_lesson_viewer"]
    url = user@another.server.com:/home/charangadh/source_code/git/virgin_lesson_viewer.git
  [submodule "public/assets/dvd_files/Virgin_lesson_viewer_staging"]
    url = user@another.server.com:/home/charangadh/source_code/git/virgin_lesson_viewer_staging.git
```

If the git folder was inside the working tree it would be easy enough - i would just do

```
git submodule add user@another.server.com:/home/charangadh/source_code/git/virgin_lesson_viewer.git public/assets/dvd_files/Virgin_lesson_viewer
```

for each of the submodules, then do "git submodule update" to update them.  But, I can't work out how to do it from the separate git folder.  Can anyone set me straight?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem well, you basically want to do a `git submodule update` in the deploy directory, but you can't, because it is not a real working directory.

My solution would be to implement a custom `git submodule update`-like command:

1. Determine which submodule version is referenced by the supermodule
2. Checkout this version into the target directory. You can do this the same way as you checkout the supermodule.

Let's say you have the following setup on your server:

- Bare repositories are stored in `/opt/repos/supermodule.git` and `/opt/repos/submodule.git`
- When you push the supermodule, you want to checkout the supermodule into `/var/www/supermodule`, and the submodule to `/var/www/supermodule/assets/submodule`

You have to do the following in the post-receive hook of `/opt/repos/supermodule.git`:

```
# Checkout supermodule
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/supermodule git checkout -f

# Determine submodule version
submodule_version=$(git ls-tree HEAD assets/submodule | awk '{print $3}')

# Checkout submodule
export GIT_DIR=/opt/repos/submodule.git
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/supermodule/assets/submodule
git checkout -f $submodule_version
```

There may be an easier solution (e.g. hack the `git submodule update` command around with some environment variables), but I often use `git ls-tree` to determine the referenced submodule version anyway.

If you push the submodules to a different server, you can still use this solution, with a little modification:

- Clone the submodule to `/opt/repos/submodule.git` on the target server
- Add a `git fetch` command before the `git checkout`

So the result is the following:

```
# Checkout submodule
export GIT_DIR=/opt/repos/submodule.git
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/supermodule/assets/submodule
git fetch
git checkout -f $submodule_version
```